# Timing of Notifications on Android Wear

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, wear-os

I'm developing a module for Android Wear which needs to operate semi-autonomously of the mobile companion app. It needs to generate notifications at a certain time. I read over [this](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html) page and it didn't say much about generating notifications at some point in the future. It seems, in order to do something similar on the Android mobile side, you have to get an AlarmManager, register a PendingIntent with it with a service that contains the code to create the notification. Is the same process necessary on Android Wear or is there some more streamlined way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is the way to go, same as in standard Android.